# MS Word commands from command line

Tags: command-line, printing, ms-word

I need to start MS Word from command line. Now, I pass these commands `/q /n /mFilePrintDefault /mFileExit` to it. In this case, I need manually press "No" on "save yes/no" dialog at the end (to close Word). What commands need to pass, to skip this (without saving or with saving doc) and automatically close Word?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Word, create a macro in Normal.dotm using this code:

```
Sub CloseWithoutSaving()
    ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
    Application.Quit
End Sub
```

Then pass /q /n /mFilePrintDefault /mCloseWithoutSaving

Comment: I'm perplexed as to how this ever worked.  

If you call `ActiveDocument.Close` first, the VB script stops executing hence it never reaches `Application.Quit`.  That's the behavior I observed: The document would close, but the Word window would stay open.  

If I put the following (and only the following) in that sub, it works as expected:  `Application.Quit SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges`.  

I'm testing this in Word 2007.  Maybe it's different in whatever version of Word you and the OP are using, but I doubt it due to the interrupted execution path.

Comment: I think the /q switch was also for quit.  Maybe that bit of code is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to print the document from the command line.  You might want to do it the same way MS does it with right-click print.  You can see details on this here:

http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ddecommandline.php